# How to convert decimal minutes to hours:minutes in SQL Server

Tags: sql

I would like to know how do you convert minutes that are >=60 to hours for example 0.70 to 1:10

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean 70 minutes to 1:10 ?

Comment: Yes it is 70minutes but I'm getting them as 0.70 from the source (bad data) hence I want to convert them to 1h10. or 0.60 to 1h00.

Comment: So are these input values literally always the number of minutes divided by 100 or is this inappropriately stored and processed data? If it's `hours.minutes` stored in a decimal data type, and you've processed it (e.g. adding values together) you should be aware that multiple inputs can produce the same output and there's no sane way to fix the data after the processing has occurred. E.g. 1 hour + 10 minutes = `1.0 + 0.1` and the result is 1.1, a "correct" value. But 55 minutes + 55 minutes = `0.55 + 0.55` and the result is 1.1, an incorrect value.

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE  @hours time = '00:00'
SELECT DATEADD(minute,70,@hours)
```

Comment: But be aware that this can only convert positive values that are less than 24 hours (since `time` is a data type for times of day rather than time spans)